# Oracle Automated Testing Suit

Tags: java, oracle, xpath

I have a script written in OATs for automation.

The script fails at a new random line every time I run it.
And every time it gives error as

> object not found

It is basically not able to locate the xpath (though it is present). When I re-run the script (without any modification in the code), it passes through and if it fails again, it fails at a new location (different xpath). Does anyone has any idea what could possibly be wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Is this question anyhow connected with oracle DB ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is pretty old, but still try to answer my best
might help someone

Script intermittently failing in your case though all the objects and property values are correct
Reason is time variation of objects to load. You have to increase synctime inbetween bojects by using WaitForPageloaded(); method